# Unexpected end of file when running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I have a small crash detect script for a teamspeak server. The only issue is that I keep getting a syntaxt error about an unexpected end of file. I am not sure if I am missing something in this from all the guides I have been following. I have also ran dos2unix since I do alot of the coding in sublime text 2 on windows.

```
#!/bin/bash
TEAMSPEAK=`ps ax | grep ts3server_linux_amd64 | grep -v grep | wc -l`

if [ $TEAMSPEAK -eq 1 ]; then
exit

else
cd /home/ryahn/ts3

if [ -f ts3server.pid ]; then
rm -f ts3server.pid
echo "File here"
. ./home/minecraft/ts3/ts3server_startscript.sh start
fi
```

Comment: As an aside, I think you mean `ps ax | grep -q'[t]s3server_linux_amd64' && exit` instead of the first five lines.  Then you are no longer missing a `fi`, either. See [useless use of `wc`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#wc).

Comment: @tripleee I will experiment with it. Right now I am having it display an echo statement so I know its working. I guess once I know its working properly, I will use your suggestion and remove the first if statement

Comment: Then at least use `grep -c` and lose the unsightly double `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `fi` for outer `if` condition.

Keep your code indented to understand it better:

```
if [ $TEAMSPEAK -eq 1 ]; then
    exit
else
    cd /home/ryahn/ts3
    if [ -f ts3server.pid ]; then
       rm -f ts3server.pid
       echo "File here"
       . ./home/minecraft/ts3/ts3server_startscript.sh start
    fi
fi
```

btw you can shorten your piped commands using `pgrep`:

```
TEAMSPEAK=$(pgrep -f ts3server_linux_amd64|wc -l)
```

Comment: I will have to remember to do that. Thank you

Comment: Probably you want to move the first `fi` to after `rm` so that the server is started regardless of whether there was an old `pid` file to clean up.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes that sounds more reasonable. I just didn't change that part.

Comment: @anubhava, tripleee I do thank you both. Works out great now <3